# where can I find the source code for python Low-level threading API _thread extension module?

Tags: python, thread-synchronization

Specifically the source code of lock, which is implemented directly by the **_thread** extension module.

Comment: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/_threadmodule.c

Comment: @TimPeters, perfect, thank you:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered by Tim Peters, the Cpython implementation:

github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/_threadmodule.c